# .NET 4.5 Async vs. TPL

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am starting to read about .NET 4.5 Async but frankly cannot get the most of it yet when to comes to the usage patter. So i will try to get that with a direct question:

I usually use .NET 4 TPL to call expensive Web services and DB calls from inside my ASP.NET application. Seems that i can achieve the same thing with Async. Is this true? When to use which?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

TPL is a library for parallel computing. .NET 4.5 async is a language feature, built on top of TPL, that makes the process easier. This is especially true when you have workflows with multiple steps.

In a nutshell, `async` lets you write your code as if it were synchronous, so the logical flow remains intact. The process of waiting for a task to complete, running specific code when that happens, can be done in a very natural fashion with `async`. The C# 5.0 and VB 11.0 compilers transform your code into the equivalent C# 4.0 and VB 10.0 code using TPL and some new `async` related types.

For an excellent under-the-hood explanation of `async`, see Jon Skeet's [Eduasync](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/) blog series.

So, how do you decide which to use? Well, `async` basically abstracts away all the complexities of creating a sequence of code fragments that are chained together with asynchronous calls. Presumably when you call a web service or access a database, you want to do something with what gets returned. `async` allows you to put the calling and processing code together, which should make your code easier to write and also easier read later on.

Comment: thanks jeffrey for the reply, but still cannot tell when to use which..say for example in the web service call example.

Comment: Use async. If you find something you cant acomplish with async then go ahead and use TPL. If that was unclear. This should be selected as the answer as its a clear concise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@Pawan about the BeginXXX/EndXXX: I think you are mixing up the things.
Looking onto C#, there are 3 different [patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx) of running parallel code:

- Deprecated: Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)
- Deprecated: Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)
- Up-to-Date: Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)

TPL is the foundation, on which the TAP is built. TPL was introduced in .NET 4. Altough TPL and TAP are somehow used equally in the Microsoftdocumentation. Either way, the async/await is then only a language feature introduced with C# 5, means .NET 4.5, to give support for the TPL in a simplified way.

[The BeginXXX/EndXXX belongs to the APM style!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) So it does not have anything to do with the TPL. These multiple versions make it difficult to keep the overview.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is internally both .Net TPL and async, uses threadpool threads. Async might be a simplified syntax for the conventional BeginXXX/EndXXX pattern.

But more importantly TPL uses, threadpool thread and you should not be using it for performing expensive operations as the same threads are used by framework itself. If you are having expensive operation(as you have mentioned) then its better to create a new stand alone thread or set the ThreadSchedular's "LongRunning" property to when using TPL.

Comment: expensive I/O != expensive CPU